# Is "Post"ed information from non-SSL to an SSL secure?

Tags: security, ssl, e-commerce, authorize.net

I am looking into Authorize.net's *new* "Direct Post Method" for handling credit card transactions. Previously, my company has been using Auth.net's AIM to process credit cards without leaving our website. This method requires that we have an SSL.

However, this new DPM that Auth.net has says that the client still pays on our website but we don't need an SSL for security. This seems a bit odd to me but that's what Auth.net says. You can see the charts here: http://developer.authorize.net/api/compare/.

So, my question is this; if I have a page hosted without an ssl (http://etc...) that posts to an SSL (https:///etc...) is the POSTed information secure?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically, the information may be secure in transit (after hitting the submit button). But the person filling out the form can't possibly know that it will be secure (so why should they trust your site?). After all, if the URL bar doesn't indicate that it is an HTTPS page, how are they supposed to know that it will POST to an HTTPS site?

I [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745047/ssl-on-login-form/1745125#1745125) about this once before. Although I was accused of being overly paranoid, I still maintain that I wouldn't trust a site with my credit card details if the page that I'm submitting from (and to, of course) are both SSL.

Look: The whole point of SSL is to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks (that's all it does). If your form isn't protected, then an attacker could modify the form to submit to wherever they want.

Man-in-the-middle attacks allow an attacker to modify or monitor information while in transit across the internet. With the prevalence of insecure wireless networks, BGP poisoning, attacks on DNS and new vulnerabilities being discovered every day, it's also becoming increasingly easy to perform a man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: You make a good point about the importance of a customer seeing an ssl on the page where they're entering their sensitive information. But, I don't understand how an attacker would be able to modify the action of a post for anyone other than themselves (through firebug or something similar.) How could that be possible?

Comment: @quakkels: I'd pose you a different question. How does your client know he's for sure on your site?

Comment: @Nikos: By the URL. e.g. `http://www.mysite.com/mycheckoutform`. I understand that the user wouldn't know that the form is posting to a secure site (e.g. `httpS://authorize.net/somewhere`) so as I said, it's a good point that the client wouldn't see an SSL in the address bar on my site. But, now I need to explain (to the powers that be) how a setup like this would be vulnerable. @Adam indicates that MITM attacks are protected by simply posting to an SSL. <see next comment>

Comment: However, he also seems to imply that an attacker could hijack the non-ssl form on the way to the client and change the Form's "Action" to a malicious URL. How is that possible to change html markup and serve it to a third party without having access to the server? Is that really possible?

Comment: -After talking with my SysAdmins, they believe that (barring access to the our servers) an attacker could not replace content flowing from our server to a client over http.

Comment: @quakkels: Your sysadmins are wrong. While an attack against your servers would affect the site security (in a number of different ways) that's also not something that SSL is a protection against. I've updated my answer with a small update on MitM attacks.